Windows USB event trace with Logman - how to open ETW file for inspection?
As usual, Windows help is 100% accurate but 100% useless (for this question, anyway).
I created an event log following the instructions here:
how-to-capture-a-usb-event-trace
Trouble is, they don't even mention how to open the file once captured.
My assumption was that it required the Windows Event Viewer, but it fails to open with the error:

I tried adding a rule to the Window Advanced Firewall as suggested, but COM + Network Access (DCOM-In) is not an available option.
The trace file is 896KB, so it definitely collected trace events.
Anyone know how to open this trace file?

I appears ETL files can be opened with Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 (a.k.a. NetMon).
